# Rails: Bootstrap Collapse doesn't work after refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, turbolinks

I have a simple Bootstrap collapse (as seen working in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wvdyqk7/3/)):

```
<h3>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        OUR NAME</a>
</h3>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <p>
        Stuff about our name.
    <p>
</div>
<h3>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        THE BOTTOM LINE BASICS</a>
</h3>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseTwo">
    <p>
    More words!
    </p>
</div>
```

I am trying to put it in an "About Us" page.  It works fine in JSFiddle, but in my Rails app, I see this behavior:

Load a different page (not About Us), then navigate to the "About Us" page: collapse works fine.

Refresh the "About Us" page: collapse doesn't work.

I figure this has something to do with Turbolinks, but nothing I'm trying is working.

Comment: Show your js or coffee code, related to this "about us" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being interference on the click event caused by [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) "smooth scrolling" script.

I fixed it by matching against "collapse":

```
   $('a[href*=#]:not([href*=#collapse])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
```